# How to insert method annotation in eclipse templates

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

When **add/edit** templates in eclipse (*preferences->java->editor->templates*) there is an `${enclosing_method}` variable. It inserts just method name.The question is how to insert method's annotation too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this from an eclipse template. The "variables" you can insert are restricted to what is offered in eclipse; you cannot do arbitrary AST-walking (though that would be a very cool addition). Sorry.

Comment: what a pitty. I would love to generate @SuppressWarnings("javadoc") to each public setter or even tell eclipse JavaDoc options to omit raising warnings for setters without JavaDoc as this is pointless clutter.